# Height property with in a link:hover

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I have some links with over. 
The over has transition in a link and in a pseudo element.

I'm setting the height of pseudo elemento to 3px, but it's getting different to another element.

In this image, the active link is OK, with 3px in pseudo heights.

[image: Normal state, without hover]

Note the bar's height, is not the same.

[image: After over the second link]

The less code:

```
.item-link {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 16px;
    transition: padding-left 0.3s ease-out;

    &:before {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: red;
        top: 6px;
        width: 0px;
        height: 3px;
        transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }
}

.item-link:hover {
    padding-left: 16px;
    color: @red;

    &:before {
        width: 8px;
    }
}
```

How to solve the pixel difference between the links with the same class and the same hover action?

Comment: The elements got predefined styles... are you cleaning them first and then giving the same style to both? I mean in css you could start by setting the link and the pseudo element like `{ font-size:0px; padding:0px; text-decoration:none; ... }` so you get clean elements... then after that give them your style attributes.

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL, thanks!
Yes, I have a default reset css. Now I'm trying to reset inside de pseudo element just for test.